# htaccess rewrite rule with : in the url on windows

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a rewrite rule that'll allow only `P00:0:R` It's for a pagination system for a website.

I tried it using php, and it works fine. But how do I get something like this into a rewrite rule?

```
$x = 'P10:10:R';

if(pageNos($x)) {
    echo 'Passed';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}

//
function pageNos($page) {
    if(preg_match('/^[P]{1}[0-9]{1,10}[:]{1}[0-9]{1,10}[:]{1}[L|R]{1}$/',$page)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

All I get with rule is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?([P]{1}[0-9]{1,10}[:]{1}[0-9]{1,10}[:]{1}[L|R]{1}+)/?$ /test/index.php [NC,L]
```

Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access /P10:2:R on this server.
```

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava It is. If i put any other rules, they work fine. But is what I've done correct? Is that the way the rule should be written for what im trying to do?

Comment: Rule can be simplified but even this one is working fine and rewrites `domain.com/P10:2:R` to `/test/index.php`. Do you have other rules as well? Where is this .htacces located?

Comment: `P10:2:R` isn't static. It can be anything. `P13:5:L` or `P100:20:R` etc. The `.htaccess` is in the site root. i.e `htdocs/sitea/.htaccess` and `test` is in `htdocs/sitea/test/index.php`

Comment: Hmm are there any other rule? Can you open `domain.com/test/index.php` in the browser?

Comment: I've removed all other rules for testing, and currently this is the only one. Yes, I can access `/test/index.php` which is only a `Hello World` file used just to test this problem.

Comment: ok create a new rule: `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /test/index.php [NC,L]` and then visit `domain.com/foo` and see what happens?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /test/index.php [NC,L]` redirects perfectly to  `domain.com/test/index.php`

Comment: ok now modify your rule: `RewriteRule ^foo:bar/?$ /test/index.php [NC,L]` and then visit `domain.com/foo:bar` and see what happens?

Comment: Now I get the same `Forbidden` message.

Comment: Hmm are you on Windows by any chance? What is your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, im on Windows 7 and my Apache version is 2.2

Comment: [Hmm on Windows Apache doesn't allow `:` in URIs](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441)

Comment: Hmm.. Does it allow `:` in Ubuntu Server? That's where this'll be hosted in the end, but I don't have access to one now.

Comment: Yes on Ubuntu `:` is allowed.

Comment: Also, has this been sorted in newer versions of Apache, or is it still the same? BTW Thanks, so much for helping. I think you could post that as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting forbidden error because [`:` is not allowed in URLs by Apache on Windows](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441). **On Windows the colon is forbidden as it is used as the drive letter separator.**

However do note that colon (`:`) is allowed as a valid character under Linux and other non-windows platforms.